# AMPScript lookup multiple criteria with data format difficulties

Tags: email, ampscript, lookup, journeybuilder

I'm trying to do a lookup with multiple criteria's. The journey doesn't want to send the email, since multiple values are returned. I'm trying to solve this, by filtering the data more, to give 1 result.

In this example, I'm trying to have only the ContractEndDate 2 days prior to today, so Enddate 09/06/2018.

The different formats I see in MC:

- **Import CSV**:  dd/mm/yyyy  (09/06/2018)
- **Visualizing in Data Extension**: dddd d MM yyyy 0:00  (zaterdag 9 juni 2018 0:00)
- **Export CSV**: dd/mm/yyyy 0:00:00  (09/06/2018 0:00:00)

My idea is that I have to match the format to the export CSV. That the visualisation of the data has nothing to do with it. OR, I can adapt the way to retreive the data from the lookup, in the import CSV format and I'll define the Now() also in the same format. 
I don't know which one I should do, I tried both, but it's not working. 
This is my try, for the first scenario:

%%[

```
SET @PersonID = _Subscriberkey 
SET @EmailAddress = Lookup("Ent.Test_B2C_Customers_ME", "EmailAddress", "PersonID", @PersonID)  
SET @Language = Lookup("Ent.Test_B2C_Customers_ME", "Language", "PersonID", @PersonID)  
SET @LastName = Lookup("Ent.Test_B2C_Customers_ME", "LastName", "PersonID", @PersonID)  
SET @FirstName = Lookup("Ent.Test_B2C_Customers_ME", "FirstName", "PersonID", @PersonID)  
SET @GSM1 = Lookup("Ent.Test_B2C_Customers_ME", "GSM1", "PersonID", @PersonID)  
SET @PostalCode = Lookup("Ent.Test_B2C_Customers_ME", "PostalCode", "PersonID", @PersonID)  
SET @City = Lookup("Ent.Test_B2C_Customers_ME", "City", "PersonID", @PersonID)
SET @Country = Lookup("Ent.Test_B2C_Customers_ME", "Country", "PersonID", @PersonID) 
SET @ExtractDate = Format(DateAdd(Now(), -2, "D"), "dd/mm/yyyy 0:00:00")  
SET @ContractID = Lookup("Ent.Test_B2C_Contracts_new_ME", "ContractID", "PersonID", @PersonID, **"ContractEndDate", @ExtractDate**)  
SET @ProductNameNL = Lookup("Ent.Test_B2C_Contracts_new_ME", "ProductNameNL", "PersonID", @PersonID)

SET @URL = CONCAT('https://specificurl.asp', '?EmailAddress=', @EmailAddress, '&Language=', @Language, '&LastName=', @LastName, '&FirstName=', @FirstName, '&GSM1=', @GSM1, '&PostalCode=', @PostalCode, '&City=', @City, '&Country=', @Country, '&ContractID=', @ContractID, '&ProductNameNL=', @ProductNameNL) 

]%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to the formatting of the date. When I create a Filtered Data Extension, that filters the Today-2, I'm able to send the email. 
In that case, I can create all the filtering outside the journey, so no need to place extra filtering in the Journey itself.

Perhaps this was the best solution to start, instead of trying to force the filters from within the journey.